# Adding Bigdata.jar or Sinbad.jar to sublime.

Tags: sublimetext3

I need to add bigjar to sublime so that I could use `import big.data.*;`
Which could be found here: https://github.com/berry-cs/big-data-cse
This link directs me to download sinbad, which I did. I now have this jar file and I don't know what to do with it.

I tried opening it. I tried going to package control but I think those are pre-downloadedable packages. I tried checking the package folder, where I am then presented with a user folder which embeds a package.Control.cache folder and other package bundles file, and dragging the sinbad.jar file in there.

I am terribly confused and just want to start my homework. If you could help or just push me in the rigth direction. I due apologize if this might be copy of another question.

```
AuctionSystem.java:5: error: package big.data does not exist
import big.data.*;
^
1 error
```

Comment: What has Java error message to do with sublime? Sublime is an Editor, which can be used as an IDE, but IMHO you do not need to import stuff in Sublime to use it in your code. Please add the jar to your classpath.

Comment: Sublime is a Text Editor, not an IDE (or a Java Runtime), so you don't add Jar files to Sublime; you add them to the `CLASSPATH` so that when you execute the `javac` command, it can find them. The `Packages` folder in Sublime is purely for packages that extend Sublime Text (which is also what Package Control holds); that location is not related to Java packages at all.